# Can i track an app on google play chart?

Tags: android, google-play

Just wondering if there is a way to track  an app in Google play chart?

For instance if it reaches top 50 of a category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several web sites and tools that tracks the ranking and notifies you about your apps. I found this below as an example,

http://www.appannie.com/apps/google-play/top/

Answer (score 0):

While it's not perfect, the AppWatch app (no connection other than as a user) is a convenient way to periodiically get your rankings for various search strings and categories.